# Replace link and word with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.bbb.com" id="name">good</a>
```

in my website.

How can I replace

- `http://www.bbb.com` with `http://www.eee.com`, and
- `good` with `bad`

by using JavaScript?

I tried this:

```
function myFunction() {
    var str = document.getElementById("name").innerHTML; 
    var res = str.replace("good", "bad");
    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = res;
}
```

Comment: There is no Java here. Java != JavaScript. Just to clarify, you *are* referencing JavaScript only, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using JavaScript which is very [distinct from Java](http://www.seguetech.com/blog/2013/02/15/java-vs-javascript). Your function seems to be over-complicating things a bit. You can simply do this:

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById('name').innerText = 'bad';
}
```

Note: `innerText` is safer than `innerHTML`.

For the link you can independently do this:

```
function myLinkFunction() {
    document.getElementById('name').href = 'http://eee.com';
}
```

Or you can combine the functions like this:

```
function myFunction() {
    var elem = document.getElementById('name');
    elem.innerText = 'bad';
    elem.href = 'http://eee.com';
}
```

Of course you'll still have to call your function (`myFunction();`) which you can do in an event handler like this:

```
<button onClick='myFunction();'>Change link</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

add this,

```
document.getElementById("name").href('http://www.eee.com');
```

So it would look like,

```
function myFunction() {
    var str = document.getElementById("name").innerHTML; 
    var res = str.replace("good", "bad");
    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = res;
    document.getElementById("name").href('http://www.eee.com');
}
```